# How to deal with long equations without having to put "&" smart places in the align environment?

Tags: equations, align, multline, split

[image: The red lines are added to show borders between environments and alignments. The picture has been edited to show what I want.]

Does there exist an environment such that long equations behaves like this?
And how do I do it without putting in & some random places in the first equation?

This is the example tex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}        
Now we just a sanity check, to make sure that the equation of $E_1$ is indeed satisfied with this isogeny, but multiplying by ${(x-8)^6}$ on both sides to make the calculations simpler.
\begin{align*}
{(x-8)^6}\left(\left(\frac{x^3 + 6 x^2 + 8 x  + 4}{(x-8)^2}\right)^3 + &5\left(\frac{x^3 + 6 x^2 + 8 x  + 4}{(x-8)^2}\right)\right)\\
&= y^2(x^3 +9 x^2 + 6x +5)\\
&= (x^3+4)(x^3 +9 x^2 + 6x +5)\\
&= x^6 + 9 x^5 + 6 x^4 + 9 x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x + 9
\end{align*}
```

I have been trying to find similar problems on stackexchange without luck.
This is my first stackexchange question. Please let me know if I can clarify something in the question.
**Edit:** Includded a minipreamble

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can improve the question by adding a suitable (minimal) preamble so to make the example compilable.

Comment: This has now been corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `multline` and a nested `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Now we just do a sanity check, to make sure that the equation of~$E_1$
is indeed satisfied with this isogeny, but multiplying by $(x-8)^6$
on both sides to make the calculations simpler:
\begin{multline*}
(x-8)^6\biggl(
  \biggl(\frac{x^3 + 6x^2 + 8x + 4}{(x-8)^2}\biggr)^{\!3} +
  5\biggl(\frac{x^3 + 6x^2 + 8x  + 4}{(x-8)^2}\biggr)
\biggr)\\
\begin{aligned}
&= y^2(x^3 +9 x^2 + 6x +5)\\
&= (x^3+4)(x^3 +9 x^2 + 6x +5)\\
&= x^6 + 9x^5 + 6x^4 + 9x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x + 9.
\end{aligned}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed some unnecessary braces and changed `\left` and `\right`. I find it better to add `\!` to exponents following large parentheses.

Comment: nested aligned.. Is than align with invoking mathenvironment?
What does "of~$E_1$" do, and why not use \left and \right?. What does \! do?

Comment: @matheny2014 Sorry, but I don't understand the first question. The `~` disallows line breaks between `of` and `$E_1$`. With `\!` the exponent is slightly moved to the left, nearer the parenthesis. If you compare the outputs, with `\left` and `\right`, the outer parentheses are way too large.

Comment: Indeed. 
In other words: What does aligned do, and what is its  relation to align?

Comment: @matheny2014 `aligned` is the inner version of `align`: same syntax and similar output, but no numbering.

Comment: Aaaah! I understand. Thank you for the clarification!